# how to click one of image list (in android espresso)

Tags: android, android-espresso

I just try use espresso to write an android uiautomator case. I have an image list. Now I want to click on one of the images. How is this done ?

```
  ---RelativeLayout
      ----imageView
      ----imageView
      ----imageView
      ----imageView
```

Comment: plz check my answer and let me know does it help u or not

Comment: what is your answer? @NehaShukla

Comment: If you can get the parent view, maybe you can try the matcher [firstChildOf()](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/E9R6jk46AOQ)

Comment: @NickDong if the imageview have a parent , the RelativeLayout's child, this method cant run.

Comment: Espresso is designed to be used with Instrumentation Test, not uiautomator tests. Are you really trying to use it with uiautomator tests?